# How to pass values from database to UI without using domain specific objects

Tags: java, c#, oop, design-patterns, concept

recently I watched some of Robert C. Martin`s lectures, and in one he mentions that NO domain specific objects should be passed to UI, and that UI shouldn`t have knowledge about domain specific objects and business logic. 
My question is how to pass all the data one domain object should have in its fields without passing domain object to UI? Should I use collecions or arrays or something else?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how complex the application is, how big the software team is. If it's a very simple application, there's no problem even directly querying database in UI, instead of adding layers of scaffolding.

Comment: One pattern might be Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) A ViewModel present information that might represent domain model objects to the UI (View).

Comment: You could use Data Transfer Objects (DTOs), which are basically just data containers without any business logic. The service layer would then know how to handle these and possibly convert them into domain entities. Dependending on your UI, DTOs can also be marshaled to/from JSON (or another format) before sending to/receiving from the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen these specific lectures, but this seems to speak to the design philosophy of N-tier architecture, such as MVC (used commonly with ASP.Net) and MVVM (used commonly with WPF applications).  The idea in these is not that your view shouldn't use custom objects, but merely that the objects you use to model your data should not hold a lot of specific business logic that might change depending on the environment.

For example, if a table in your database is `BillSummaries`, you might have an object called `BillSummary` with a `customer`, a `date`, a `subtotal`, a `fees total`, a `tax total`, and a `grand total`.  You could use a data access layer to retrieve the data from the database and create the objects (the reason for this is so that you can easily change your approach and create different data access classes for SQL Server, Oracle, and a web service without changing any of your UI code - the UI doesn't care where the object came from, just that it gets the type of object it expects).

The object itself should be as simple as possible, so that you can easily pass it back and forth between different applications on different platforms (such as a .Net application communicating with a Java web service, or a .Net application that has a Xamarin mobile app that supports it.)  The more custom data types and built-in logic you use, the more effort you will typically need to share the object between dissimilar projects.

If you have code that calculates the amount of taxes and fees, that is an example of business logic.  It belongs in a different layer (the controller or the viewmodel).  The reason for this is that if you expand into a different country or region, you might have different types of fees requiring different calculations.  If you do this, you can replace the viewmodel without changing UI code, or without changing your object classes (the model), or the data access code.  You can even run different controllers or viewmodels side-by-side to support different customers depending on where they live.

So, to cut to the chase, without having seen the lecture but based on what you are describing, I think he means that your view/UI should expect only "skeleton type objects" that contain basic data fields.  You can bind your UI to these, or use them as a tool to pass data from layer to layer.  To maximize the reusability and flexibility of your code, though, you should avoid including code that communicates with the database or code that implements specific business logic in these model objects.  When he speaks about "domain-specific", I suspect he is referring to things that are relevant to the way that the organization stores their data, the business rules that the organization has in place, etc. (these things belong in other layers.)